# How to change list item layout after asynchronous image download in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, asynchronous, android-cursoradapter

I have been given the task to make an app to load some JSON from an API which contains some metadata and links to some images that I need to load asynchronously. On start the app should display a `ListView` containing the metadata as text and populate the list with the images as they load.

I want to know whether I should use two different layouts for before and after the image has loaded or I should just use the one layout and assume that the text will take up the full layout if no image is available?

If I am to use two different views, can I implement this by using a `CursorAdapter` to bind my data the `ListView` and use `getItemViewType` to choose the view? The issue is that I don't know how to use the callback from my asynchronous loader to change the view type given that the only parameter for `getItemViewType` is position.

EDIT: I am trying to do this without using a placeholder image or an external library.

Thanks

stan-sack

Comment: You can use a placeholder for the image.

Comment: you can use this awesome library https://github.com/koush/ion  
you dont have to make two different layouts for before and after.

Comment: thanks for the advice guys but i'm really looking to do this without placeholders or an external library. its more an exercise about dealing with two layout views

Answer (score 1):

See picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. The library manages the loading of the images. Glide also does similar